# Proving that a continuous function is constant

Tags: general-topology

Suppose that $(X,T)$ is a locally compact, non-compact Hausdorff space.

Locally compact means: for each $x\in X$, there exists a local base at $x$ consisting of compact sets.

Let $T' = \{\varnothing\}\cup\{X-K: K$ is $T$-compact$\}$. This is a topology on $X$.

How to prove that any continuous function, from $(X,T')$ to $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology, is constant?

I have been thinking about this for a while, and I couldn't come up with something. Hints are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Show that $\langle X,T'\rangle$ does not contain two disjoint non-empty open sets. (It’s important here that $\langle X,T\rangle$ is not compact.) Then get a contradiction if some $T'$-continuous $f:X\to\Bbb R$ is non-constant. (Note that $\Bbb R$ can be replaced by any Hausdorff space.)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I figured it out. This is part of an exercise I'm solving, where in all the other parts I only used Hausdorffness. There is one part remaining: to find the $T'$-closure of a given subset of $X$. But here I also didn't have to use local compactness, I argued that the $T'$-closure is either $X$ or the $T$-closure itself. Do you think that local compactness might have been useful in finding the closure? Also, side-question: does this topology have a special name?

Comment: @Cauchy: You’re welcome. Yes, the $T'$-closure of $A$ is the $T$-closure if that is compact in $\langle X,T\rangle$ and $X$ otherwise. I don’t see why local compactness was specified. It does mean that the one-point compactification $X^*$ of $\langle X,T\rangle$ is $T_2$, and $T'$ is the nbhds of the point at infinity in $X^*$ (and $\varnothing$), but I don’t see the point unless it’s relevant to some other part of the exercise. I don’t think that I’ve encountered the topology before; it does give a nice example of an [irreducible space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperconnected_space).

Answer (score 2):

If $f: X\to \mathbb R$ continuous, and $x_1,x_2\in f(X)$, with $x_1\ne x_2$, then
$$
(x_1-a,x_1+a)\cap (x_2-a,x_2+a)=\varnothing,
$$
where $a=\frac{1}{2}\lvert x_1-x_2\rvert$, and hence
$$
f^{-1}(x_1-a,x_1+a)\cap f^{-1}(x_2-a,x_2+a)=\varnothing.
$$
But $\,f^{-1}(x_1-a,x_1+a)\ne\varnothing\,$
and $\,f^{-1}(x_2-a,x_2+a)\ne\varnothing$, and hence
$$
f^{-1}(x_1-a,x_1+a)=X\setminus K_1,\quad
f^{-1}(x_2-a,x_2+a)=X\setminus K_2
$$
where $K_1, K_2$ compact in the first topology. But, 
$$
\varnothing=(X\setminus K_1)\cap(X\setminus K_2)=X\setminus (K_1\cup K_2),
$$
and hence $K_1\cup K_2=X$, which means that $X$ would be compact in the first topology. Contradiction.